# npm live-server Vunerability

Tags: npm, fedora

Hi everyone I recently updated to fedora 35, I installed node js which come with npm.
Now I have a question about my live-server install when I did the install I got A sort of error message saying that I have "2 high severity vulnerabilities. Does anyone had that kind of messages and if so, how did you fix it ? Than you.

Answer (score 0):

NPM keeps bothering me the same way it doing to you.
Hence I shifted to the yarn

Try using yarn

Install cmd is
***npm i -g yarn***

And download the same package it will not show you such messages!!